# How to use ping -f until file = false

Tags: bash, ping, sudo

I would like to execute the `ping -f` command until `cat ~/.test = false`, but

```
until [[ `cat ~/.test` == false ]]; do sudo ping -f 10.0.1.1; done
```

only checks one time. How to kill command automatically when the file changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach will not work for two reasons:

1. The `ping` command runs until it is interrupted. In other words: There will only be one loop iteration ever, because you will be stuck in the loop.
2. `cat ~/.test` will always be "true" (i.e. successful), as long as the file exists. It will only be "false" (i.e. exit with a non-zero error code), if the file does not exist (any more). `cat` is **not** suited for checking file changes - unless that change is creating or deleting the file.

With that in mind, you should probably try something along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

# launch the ping process and leave it running in the background
ping -f 10.0.1.1 &
# get the process ID of the previous command's process
PING_PID=$!
# until the file ~/.test does not exist any more,
# do the stuff in the loop ...
until ! test -f ~/.test; do
  # sleep for one second
  sleep 1
done
# kill the ping process with the previously stored process ID
kill $PING_PID
```

The script is untested and may not work completely, but it should give you an idea how to solve your problem.

**Edit:**
If it does not need to be a flood ping, you can use this simpler script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# As long as the file ~/.test exists,
# send one ping only to the target.
while test -f ~/.test; do
  ping -c 1 10.0.1.1  
done
```

This approach was suggested by twalberg.

Another advantage of this approach (besides the simpler script) is that you do not need to `sudo` the ping command any more, because unlike flood pings the "normal" pings do not need root privileges.

Comment: I would suggest `ping -c 1 10.0.1.1` inside the `until` (or `while`) loop, rather than backgrounding and killing...

Comment: @twalberg: Yes, that would usually be a better approach. However, the `-f` option to ping stands for flood ping, and just doing one ping kind of defeats the flooding. So unless the flood ping is not required, the current way with background and killing later seems to be OK.

Comment: Shouldn't `while [ test -f ~/.test ]; do` be `while test -f ~/.test; do` or `while [ -f ~/.test ]; do`?

Comment: @user000001: Yep, you are right. I did not test this loop before posting it, but now that I've done it I see that there was a syntax error. Thanks for spotting the mistake, I've edited my answer.

Comment: @1072: Cannot reproduce that error. The script works for me with Bash 4.3.30.

Comment: @Striezel I tried to write it inline: `ping -f 10.0.1.1 & PING_PID=$!; [until ! test -f ~/.test]; do sleep 1 done; kill $PING_PID`

Comment: @1072: That inline variant will not work, because you need a space after the `[` and before the `]`. Without that bash can't parse the loop condition. And even than I am not so sure that it will work. If in doubt, just keep to the "long" version above where every command has its own line.

Comment: @Striezel I need inline ... `ping -f '10.0.1.1' & PING_PID=$$; while [ -e '~/ddos-10.0.1.1' ]; do sleep 1; done; kill $PING_PID;` is now my command, but it doesn't stop executing when I remove the file